# Stateful checks in gatling websocket scenario

Tags: scala, websocket, gatling

I have a gatling scenario where I subscribe to a websocket and want to check the incoming messages for internal consistency.

E.g. the messages coming over the websocket are `<user>: <sequence number>`, and I want to check that for each user string, the sequence number is continuous and increasing from 1.

```
a: 1
b: 1
a: 2
b: 2
a: 1 // <= this would be an error because last a was 2, so should be 3
```

My first approach was to store something like a `Map[String, Int]` in a session variable. But it seems to me that the gatling webservice API does not allow storing non-string session variables:

This (just concatenating everything we got over the WS) compiles:

```
def updateState(text: String, session: Session): String = {
  session("wsState").as[String] + "\n" + text
}

val scn = scenario("String")
  .exec(ws("Connect WS")
    .open("/indexWS?topic=${topic}")
    .check(
      wsListen
        .within(3600.seconds)
        .until(10)
        .message
        .find
        .transform(updateState _)
        .saveAs("wsState"))
)
```

But as soon as the updateState function returns something other than string, it does not compile anymore

```
def updateState(text: String, session: Session): Map[String, Int] = {
  session("counts").as[Map[String, Int]] // + update from message text
}

val scn = scenario("String")
  .exec(ws("Connect WS")
    .open("/indexWS?topic=${topic}")
    .check(
      wsListen
        .within(3600.seconds)
        .until(10)
        .message
        .find
        .transform(updateState _)
        .saveAs("counts"))
)
```

Here is the error message:

```
[error]  found   : io.gatling.core.check.CheckBuilder[io.gatling.http.check.ws.WsCheck,String,String,Int]
[error]  required: io.gatling.http.check.ws.WsCheckBuilder
[error]     (which expands to)  io.gatling.core.check.CheckBuilder[io.gatling.http.check.ws.WsCheck, String, _, String]
```

Now obviously I could just serialize the map to a string on every update. But I would rather avoid that. Non-string session variable seem to be allowed in gatling, so why not in websockets?