# How do I control order of execution of exec statements in Gatling scenario?

Tags: scala, gatling

In the following code snippet I want the session function to execute before the HttpRequestbBuilder SolrProductionDataRequestBuilder, but I can't make it happen...  Relatively new to Scala and Gatling, so please forgive a blatant error here...
(I need to modify the session keys to make them palatable to Solr before adding them to the http request - Solr allows (requires) duplicate keys. Solr queries (derived from a Splunk log) are read into the session by a tsv feeder)

```
  var scn = scenario("Solr load scenario using production solr request traffic")
    .feed(queryParameterFeeder)
    .exec(session => {
      duplicateGatlingSessionMap(session.attributes)
      session
    })
    .exec(
      SolrProductionDataRequestBuilder("wow", gatlingSessionMap)
        .build()
        .asJSON
        .check(status.is(200))
    )
   .pause(3000 milliseconds, 5000 milliseconds)
```

Comment: You need to pull the call out of that exec block and stuff it into the static code -- say, right after **var scn**.  Those **.exec** blocks execute in parallel.

Comment: No, exec blocks execute sequentially for a given virtual user.

Answer (score 1):

From [Session API](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/session_api.html) doc:

> Session instances are immutable!

I don't know what your `duplicateGatlingSessionMap` does, but your `exec(function)` only returns the **original session**.

Note: don't use `var`, use `val`. There's no reason to use reassignable references.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephane already mentioned "sessions" are immutable, i.e. in your first exec() you are not returning modified session. Otherwise the flow of the exec() statements is as written in code, hence in sequence.

Not sure what your code does but preferred/idiomatic way is to write it like this:

```
def duplicateGatlingSessionMap(session: Session) Session = {
  // your session modification logic here
}

val scn = scenario("Solr load scenario using production solr request traffic")
  .feed(queryParameterFeeder)
  .exec( session => // above defined function which modifies the session and returns it back
    duplicateGatlingSessionMap(session) 
  ) 
  .exec(
  SolrProductionDataRequestBuilder("wow", gatlingSessionMap)
      .build()
      .asJSON
      .check(status.is(200))
  )
  .pause(3000 milliseconds, 5000 milliseconds)
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: see comments

Comment: Nope, this is wrong. Creating an ActionBuilder or an Action at runtime in a function is pointless: it's not attached attached to the rest of the scenario chain that's already statically built at load time.

Comment: Not sure I understand. In my example I'm just calling function in exec which modifies session, that is it returns modified copy. Which IMO is Ok.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480244/how-do-i-make-gatling-capture-request-while-reading-from-the-session/35482812#35482812

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly .. Sorry for confusion

Comment: No pro. Thanks for helping answering :)