# Unable to evaluate EL while creating Gatling scenario

Tags: performance, scala, load-testing, gatling

I am creating scenario with repeat block. As I need index based request to be generated.

```
def scnWithLoop() = scenario("scenarioName").repeat(counter, "counter") {
    exec (session => {
    val index: Integer = Integer.getInteger(session.attributes.get("counter").get.toString());
    session.set("index", index)
    session
})

exec(
      http("scenarioName")
        .post(contextPath)
        .headers(headers)
        .body(StringBody(getData("${index}".toInt)))
        .check(status.in(expectedCodes))
    ).pause(20 seconds)
}
```

But this doesn't evaluate EL ${index} and gives me error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${index}"
```

Gatling Version: 2.0.0-M3a

Appreciate any help!!!

Comment: Did you try using triple quotes? `"""${index}"""`

Comment: you can directly use "counter" ` .repeat(2,"counter").exec(http("${counter}"))`
no need to save it to new session var, it creates one automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Convenient interpolation of session values like `"${index}"` works only when the string is implicitly converted to gatling's expression. This dark magic of scala will be broken by something like your expression `"${index}".toInt`. You will probably have to work with the gatling's session explicitly, as per [the session EL documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.1/session/expression_el.html) :

> ....
>
> For example, `queryParam("latitude", "${latitude}".toInt + 24)` won’t
>   work, the program will blow on `"${latitude}".toInt` as this String
>   can’t be parsed into an Int.
>
> The solution here would be to pass a function:
>
> `session => session("latitude").validate[Int].map(i => i + 24)`.